# How can I create A Report based on counties?

Tags: groups, reports

As part of our initial member sign-up, we ask folks to list the name of the county where they reside.  I want to create a report identifying members who live in specific counties.  e.g.  A grouping of all members who live in the following counties:  Audubon, Guthrie & Adair.

I cannot seem to find a way to create a report that allows me to use the category of 'county'.  Do I need to create the group first?  How do I do that?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question!  I don't believe there's a report that lets you filter by county "out of the box".  Instead, you can create a smart group, then filter by that:

- Go to **Search menu » Search Builder**.
  [image]
- Build a search using the criteria as I've outlined them in Screenshot 1 below.  Note that assuming you're in the US, there's two "Adair" counties, but no good way to know which is which.  Look at your search results to make sure you're getting the right one.
- Press "Search".

**Depending on your needs, you might be done!**  This may be all you need.  If you need to use this as the basis of other searches/reports (e.g. "show donations from residents of these 3 counties"), you'll want a "smart group":

- From search results, select "All records", then select "Group - create smart group" from the "Actions" menu.  See screenshot 2 below, though if you're using an older version of CiviCRM than 4.7, it may look slightly different.
- Name your group, press "Save Smart Group".

Now, when doing future searches/reports, you can use the results of the "3 county" search as a "base group" to search/report within.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can only build a search using the parameters that CIVI offers me.  How did you add the 'county', 'primary' and county name slots.  My civic will not let me do this.  Unless I am too inexperienced to know who to add fields.

Comment: Jon is using Search Builder (under Search in Admin Menu) rather than Adv Search. May be the hint you need.

Comment: I guess I just don't know how to use this because I cannot add more than what seems to be allowed.  Hopeless.

Comment: @IFU I'm sorry you're having problems!  I'll add a screenshot showing how to get to Search Builder.  If you still have problems after that, please add a comment letting us know if you found Search Builder.  And of course, if we DO answer your question, please click the checkmark to show that this is a good answer!

Comment: @IFU if this isn't helpful, you may want to consider having your organization purchase a CiviCRM training, or hire a consultant for some Q&A over at https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors